# Unity3D behaves differently in scene and game view

Tags: unity

We are having AI being able to shoot. Everything works fine when having them play in Scene view, but when going into Game view the position they are shooting from is different.

Does anyone know what could cause this? That the Unity "Scene view" behaves other than "Game view"?

Hope there's anyone there to help us out, thanks in advance.

Comment: As we're working over Unity networking, we figured out that the host is supposed to always see the AI otherwise it won't work correctly. Is there any better way than hard coding the camera to a specific position?

Comment: We definitely need more information on this, could you paste screen shots or something to visualize what is going on?

Comment: If you want help fixing a bug in your code, it would help to show that code.